# How to open a file on Mac OS X using Python

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

In Python code, I tried with `subprocess` to open a file:

```
ss=subprocess.Popen(filename,shell=True)
ss.communicate
```

It is working fine on Windows, as it is waiting for the file to close to execute the next instruction. But, it is not even opening the file on Mac OS X 10.8.2. Then, I tried with:

```
subprocess.call(['open', '-W', fileName])
```

It is opening the file but the issue is, it opens the file in text-editor, so I have to close the opened file and need to quit the text-editor from Dock, then it execute the next instruction.
What I want is to open a file with the default editor and it should wait until the opened file is closed. And as soon as the open file is closed, it should then execute the next instruction and the text editor should also quit automatically from Dock.

Comment: Your first example does not wait for the file to close for me on Windows. Perhaps you meant `ss.communicate()`. `ss.wait()` works, too.

Comment: What kind of file are you opening? That may affect your results.

Comment: @martineau it will open any type of file like .txt,.odt,.docx. ss.communicate() will hold control till subprocess is finished.

Comment: Make sure that `filename` fas execute permissions.  Try `ss=subprocess.Popen('./' + filename,shell=True)